# Como resetear variable de incremento en c#

Tags: c#, formularios

Estoy realizando un sistema de evaluación en csharp con windows forms.
Al correr mi programa y al contestar la evaluación me arroja correctamente mi resultado, el problema es cuando vuelvo a seleccionar esa misma evaluación la contesto y me suma la calificación anterior con la otra. así tengo mi código:

```
         `public partial class EvaluacioTableros : Form
{
    public static int score = 0;
    int i, c = 0;
    string correctop;

    public EvaluacioTableros()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    returnclass rc = new returnclass();

    private void EvaluacioTableros_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = Convert.ToInt32(rc.scalarReturn("select min(p_id) from preguntas where p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl));
        label1.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_title from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
        radioButton1.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_opa from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
        radioButton2.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_opb from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
        radioButton3.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_opc from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
        radioButton4.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_opd from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
        correctop = rc.scalarReturn("select p_opcorrect from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
    }`

   ` string s, selectedvalue = " ";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        realizarEva();

    }
    `introducir el código aquí`
      private void realizarEva()
    {

       
        c++;
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            selectedvalue = radioButton1.Text;

        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            selectedvalue = radioButton2.Text;
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            selectedvalue = radioButton3.Text;
        }
        else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        {
            selectedvalue = radioButton4.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor selecciona una opción");
        }
        if (selectedvalue == correctop)
        {
            score++;

        }`



        `s = rc.scalarReturn("select min(p_id) from preguntas where p_id>" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
        if (s.Equals(""))
        {
            

            MessageBox.Show("Finalizo su evaluación");
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {

            i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
            label1.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_title from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
            radioButton1.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_opa from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
            radioButton2.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_opb from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
            radioButton3.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_opc from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
            radioButton4.Text = rc.scalarReturn("Select p_opd from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
            correctop = rc.scalarReturn("select p_opcorrect from preguntas where p_id=" + i + "and p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);

        }`

      `raddbtn();
 

`introducir el código aquí
        string lastquestions = rc.scalarReturn("select max(p_id)from preguntas where p_fk_crs=" + Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl);
```

if (lastquestions.Equals(i.ToString()))
{
float per = (score / c + 1) * 100;
insertclass iC = new insertclass();
iC.insert_score(score.ToString(), FormLogin1.LoginNam, Indicadores_Antropometricos.exam_tbl, per.ToString(), System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());`

```
            Resultado1 lc = new Resultado1();
            lc.Show();

            this.Enabled = false;` 
        }

    }
    public void raddbtn()
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
      
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @Ericcosme Agrega la clase insertclass, indica en que valor se almacena la suma de la calificación.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero ya lo solucione.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente reinicia el valor de la evaluación cuando realices otra evaluación, esto puedes realizarlo al iniciar el método, por ejemplo:

```
private void realizaEvaluacion(){
   score = 0; //Reinicia valor
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ya lo hice pero aun asi no me deja y me los sigue sumando.

Comment: agrega el codigo completo para ver como reiniciar la variable

Comment: Asi esta mi codigo, espero me puedan ayudar. gracias.